# Bootstrap sub column heights not the same

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem making all the heights of my columns the same.
I use Bootstrap the size them, but I use sub divs which is where my problem comes in.

[Here is a DEMO of my problem](https://www.bootply.com/EpHI97LJ4y)

The first "table" is one from an example taken from a  [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/2240163)

The second one is my example. I need the inned cells to be of the same height as the max row height.

Any ideas please

Here is a preview of the layouts.

[image]

Comment: have you tried giving `height:100%;` to the " **Labour** " `div`?. Does that give you the result you want?

Comment: you can use `.col-sm-10 {
    display: flex;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css, and you will get the result , https://www.bootply.com/ffG102jhjs

```
.row.equal .col-sm-3 > div {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked partially. I used a combination of `.col-sm-10 { display: flex; }` aswell to make it work.